# i want to load first element from api initially , but after making change to other user data the component goes back to first element data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

//here i want to show first array data initially, but not on every state change or api call

```
useEffect(() => {
    data?.delivery_boys?.map((d, index) => {
      if (index === 0) {
        setDeliveryBoy(d);
      }
    });
    return () => {
      data;
    };
  }, [data]);
```

---

//here i am mutating data and setting state again

```
 const handleOnSubmit = () => {
    setAssignCustomerId(assignCustomerId);
    console.log(assignCustomerId, "assgnied ");
    toggleModal();
    const id = typeof deliveryBoy !== "undefined" && deliveryBoy.id;
    const params = { deliveryBoyId: id, assignCustomerId };
    assignCustomerMutation.mutate(params, {
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        setDeliveryBoy(data?.delivery_boy);
        queryClient.setQueryData([GET_DELIVERY_BOY_LIST.name, params], data);
        queryClient.invalidateQueries([GET_DELIVERY_BOY_LIST.name]);
      },
    });
  };
```

Comment: The useEffect will rerun every time data is changed. Remove it from the dependency array if you only want to runt useEffect once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the line you want in the `useEffect` is to only set it if there is no deliveryBoy.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (!deliveryBoy){
      // your code
    }

  }, [data]);
```

However in the useEffect i dont think you need to map over all the items either, so you can rewrite it like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (!deliveryBoy) {
      setDeliveryBoy(data?.delivery_boys?.[0])  
    }
  }, [data]);
```